# tikz usecase diagram send and receive shape

Tags: tikz-pgf, shapes

Im searching for a send and receive shape that has to look like this:
[image: umlsendandreceive]

Is there some standard shape.misc to implement or even a manual to the shape.misc package?

Comment: `signal` shape (from `shapes.symbols`)  is what you want, combined with options `signal to=east` or `signal from=west`

Comment: Im not able to work that out. And i can't find any help online to this special symbols... Do you have some more information?

Comment: See if my answer helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.symbols,positioning}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[signal, draw, signal to=east, fill=cyan!20] (1) {Kellner rufen!};
    \node[signal, draw, signal from=west, fill=cyan!20, below=of 1] (2) {Gast ruft Kellner}; 
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

This is the result:

[image: Result]

I think that `shapes.symbols` requires a recent version of PGF/TikZ. You can read more about it at [page 709 of the latest PGF manual](http://osl.ugr.es/CTAN/graphics/pgf/base/doc/pgfmanual.pdf#page=709).